# LuaInterface Memory Leak Issue

Tags: c#, memory-leaks, lua

I have discovered I have a bad memory leak in a C#/Lua LuaInterface Project. I have written a simple test function in C# that is called from Lua in a loop every 0.5 secs. I can see the Lua memmory usage is increasing with each loop. My latest C# side code is

```
  public LuaTable testMemTable()
  {
     LuaTable tabx = m_lua.GetTable("tabx");

     if (tabx != null)
     {
        tabx.Dispose();
        tabx = null;

        GC.Collect();
        GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
     }


     m_lua.NewTable("tabx");
     tabx = m_lua.GetTable("tabx");

     for (int i = 0; i < 20000; i++)
        tabx[i] = i * 10;

     return  tabx;
  }
```

despite doing tabx.Dispose() and a tabx=null and then forcing a GC I am still seeing that the memory is not being freed.  There is no LuaInterface function to free up a previously allocated table, so I am a loss at what else I can do to free the memory ?

The Lua side code is very simple

```
while true do

    myAPILibs.testMemTable()

    if tabx ~= nil then
        print(string.format("Size = %d", #tabx))
    else
        print(string.format("Size = nil"))
    end

    print(tabx, tabx[111])

    myAPILibs.sleep(500)

    print("Before ", collectgarbage("count") * 1024)
    collectgarbage("collect")
    print("After ", collectgarbage("count") * 1024)

end
```

Any help is solving my memory leak problem would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks again

Geoff

Answer (score 2):

I need to rant about LuaInterface a bit, because it makes this problem very difficult to solve -- in some cases, it's even impossible not to leak memory.

CLR object proxies in LuaInterface (and NLua) do not provide finalizers that release the Lua reference.<sup>1</sup>  You must dispose each and every CLR object that references a Lua object.  If you forget once, the Lua object can never be garbage collected.

To make matters worse, you cannot properly dispose a reference that you return from a CLR method that is called by Lua.  If you dispose the reference before you return it, it's gone and you can't return it anymore.  If you don't dispose it, the CLR reference is leaked.  There are code gymnastics that you can do to properly dispose the reference, but there is no reason at all that this kind of work should be required on your part.

Now let me get off of my soapbox and address your code.

There are many places in all of your methods where you leak these objects.  Your use of `GetTable()` belies your misunderstanding of how it works.  Each time you invoke this method, you get a *new* CLR object that references the Lua table referenced by that Lua global variable.  Your usage of it appears to assume that you can do `m_lua.GetTable("tabx").Dispose()` and accomplish something -- all this does is create a new CLR reference and then dispose of *just that one reference.*  In other words, it's an expensive way to do nothing at all.

**Every invocation of `GetTable()` should have a corresponding disposal** (or use C#'s `using` block to do the disposal for you).

To clarify, disposing the CLR `LuaTable` object *does not* destroy the Lua table!  All it does is release *that particular* CLR reference to the table.

This holds true for *every* LuaInterface type that references a Lua object, including functions, which is another place where you potentially leak.

Here I will show the problems with each method, and how you would rewrite it to address these problems.

```
public LuaTable testMemTable()
{
   // This code does nothing.  You get a new reference to the Lua table
   // object, and then you immediately dispose it.  You can remove this
   // whole chunk of code; it's a really expensive no-op.
   LuaTable tabx = m_lua.GetTable("tabx");

   if (tabx != null)
   {
      tabx.Dispose();
      tabx = null;

      GC.Collect();
      GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
   }


   m_lua.NewTable("tabx");

   // You create a new CLR object referencing the new Lua table, but you
   // don't dispose this CLR object.
   tabx = m_lua.GetTable("tabx");

   for (int i = 0; i < 20000; i++)
      tabx[i] = i * 10;

   return  tabx;
}
```

The correct way to write this method would be:

```
public void testMemTable()
{
    m_lua.NewTable("tabx");

    using (LuaTable tabx = m_lua.GetTable("tabx")) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 20000; i++) {
            tabx[i] = i * 10;
        }
    }
}
```

(Note that I changed the return type to void since you never use the return value.)

```
public LuaTable getNewTableCSharp()
{
    // You don't dispose the function object.
    var x = lua.GetFunction("getNewTableLua");
    // You don't dispose the table object.
    var retValTab = (LuaTable)x.Call()[0];

    return retValTab;
}
```

Note that since the `getNewTableLua` function is never reassigned, you're not actually leaking the Lua function, but with each invocation of this function you *are* leaking a slot in a Lua table that holds a reference to that function.

Now here's the rub: because this function is called from Lua and returns a reference to a Lua object, **you cannot fix both leaks**, you can only fix the function leak:

```
public LuaTable getNewTableCSharp()
{
    using (var x = lua.GetFunction("getNewTableLua")) {
        // Still leaks, but you can't do anything about it.
        return (LuaTable)x.Call()[0];
    }
}
```

To get back on my soapbox, consider using [Eluant](https://github.com/cdhowie/Eluant) instead, which is a set of Lua bindings for the CLR (much like LuaInterface), except that it solves the memory management problems.  (Disclaimer: I am the author of Eluant.)

In particular, it solves the problems you have run into here:

- Eluant's CLR objects that reference Lua objects have finalizers which will queue the Lua reference to be released later.  If you forget to dispose a CLR object referencing a Lua object, it will eventually get collected anyway.  (But you should still dispose references ASAP, preferably using C#'s `using` blocks, to make sure that Lua's GC can collect the objects in a timely manner.)
- If you return a CLR object reference to a Lua object in a method that was invoked by Lua, Eluant will dispose the reference for you before it returns control to Lua.

---

<sup>1</sup> [See here](https://github.com/Jakosa/LuaInterface/blob/master/Core/LuaInterface/LuaBase.cs#L58).  The finalizer is present, but the disposer does not release the Lua object reference if it was called by the finalizer.  In other words, the finalizer basically doesn't do anything at all.  Note that because Lua is not thread-safe, it's not safe to actually release the Lua reference at this point, but the release operation could be queued for later.  LuaInterface does not do this; [Eluant does](https://github.com/cdhowie/Eluant/blob/master/Eluant/LuaRuntime.cs#L483).

Answer (score 1):

**Short answer**

Replace `lua.newTable("testTable")` with
`lua.doString("for key,value in ipairs(testTable) do testTable[key]=nil end");`

There will be no memory leak and your code works fine.

**Long answer**

Lets say you had lua script like this:

```
newTable = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14}   
newTable = {}
```

If you do this on the Lua side, even though you never actually cleared the original table, there are no leaks. Lua somehow knows to dispose of the table before reassigning it.

However, if you have any C# references to the table before you set it to an empty table, even though lua disposes of its stuff, the C# references are not disposed of; apparently it acts as if the instance has created a brand new table. What you need to do to reset the table is:

```
for key,value in ipairs(testTable) do   
   testTable[key] = nil   
end
```

Your problem isn't really a memory leak, it's that your static Lua instance is loading multiple versions of the table because of the way it's being reset.